# Github pages does not update without clearing cache

Tags: html, github, github-pages

I have been creating my first website with GitHub pages and it's working, but it's annoying to have to clear the cache, or open an incognito window, every time I add something new.

I plan on using Jekyll to be able to test stuff before I post to the website but I was wondering if this happens to everyone, and if so whether there is a way to change it?

I wouldn't want people to see a previous version of my website because they haven't cleared the cache.

Answer (score 0):

You could add to your pages a cache busting directive, as [seen here](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/cache-busting-jekyll-github-pages), by Todd Motto:

```
<link href="{{ "/css/main.css" | prepend: site.baseurl }}?{{ site.time | date: '%s%N' }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

> Once I’ve posted this blog (i.e. now, as you’re reading) it will have changed again. This means no hard refreshes for browsers or funky styles being shown if you’re making important site updates.